# Pipe stdin into a shell script through php

Tags: php, pipe, stdin, shell-exec

We have a command line php application that maintains special permissions and want to use it to relay piped data into a shell script.

I know that we can read STDIN with:

```
while(!feof(STDIN)){
    $line = fgets(STDIN);
}
```

But how can I redirect that STDIN into a shell script?

The STDIN is far too large to load into memory, so I can't do something like:

```
shell_exec("echo ".STDIN." | script.sh");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using xenon's answer with popen seems to do the trick.

```
// Open the process handle
$ph = popen("./script.sh","w");
// This puts it into the file line by line.
while(($line = fgets(STDIN)) !== false){
    // Put in line from STDIN. (Note that you may have to use `$line . '\n'`. I don't know
    fputs($ph,$line);
}
pclose($ph);
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Devon said, `popen`/`pclose` are very useful here.

```
$scriptHandle = popen("./script.sh","w");
while(($line = fgets(STDIN)) !== false){
    fputs($scriptHandle,$line);
}
pclose($scriptHandle);
```

Alternatively, something along the lines of `fputs($scriptHandle, file_get_contents("php://stdin"));` might work in the place of a line-by-line approach for a smaller file.

Comment: Well, this should be executed not written but your code gave me an idea.  Using popen instead of fopen seems to do the trick.  Thanks.